# Sencha Touch 2 geolocation using Google Maps

Tags: geolocation, maps, touch, extjs

I'm trying to implement geolocation on my app written in sencha framework, but I don't really know how to implement geolocation using Sencha Touch 2 and Google Maps Api.
I have following code:

```
Ext.define('App.view.WhereAmI', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'whereAmI',
    //? fullscreen: true,

    requires: [
        'Ext.Map'
    ],

    config: {
        layout: 'fit',
        scrollable: true,
        styleHtmlContent: true,
        style: 'text-align: center; background-color:white;',

        items: 
        [
            {
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                docked: 'top',
                title: 'Where Am I?',
                minHeight: '60px',
                items: [
                    {
                        ui: 'back',
                        xtype: 'button',
                        id: 'backButton',
                        text: 'Powrót',
                    },

                    {
                        minHeight: '60px',
                        right: '5px',
                        html: ['<img src="resources/images/Image.png"/ style="height: 100%; ">',].join(""),
                    },
                ],          
            },
            {
                xtype:'map',
            },
        ]
    },
    //launch : function () { },
});
```

What do I exactly need to add to this view to implement marker with my current location?

Thanks for help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203933/sencha-touch-2-display-current-location-on-map

Hope this helps.

Comment: I found this after I had wrote this post and it helped, but thanks for your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using geolocation :

```
        var geo = Ext.create('Ext.util.Geolocation', {
        autoUpdate:false,
        listeners:{
            locationupdate:function (geo) {
                console.log('Current latitude: ' + geo.getLatitude() + 'Long: ' + geo.getLongitude());
            },
            locationerror:function (geo, bTimeout, bPermissionDenied, bLocationUnavailable, message) {
                if (bTimeout) {
                    alert('Timeout occurred.');
                } else {
                    alert('Error occurred.');
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

or add

`useCurrentLocation:true,`

in sencha touch map